# Правильно ли я понял как работает это создание объектов?

Tags: c++

Вот код с примером

```
#include <iostream>

class Object {
public:
        Object();
};

class scoped_ptr {
        Object *pObj;
public:
        scoped_ptr(Object *pObject);

};
Object::Object() {
}

scoped_ptr::scoped_ptr(Object *pObject) {
        pObj = pObject;
}

int main() {
        scoped_ptr p = new Object();
}
```

То есть это не указатель

```
scoped_ptr p = new Object();
```

и все ок. А вот указатель

```
Object *p = new Object();
```

и тоже все ок. Почему так происходит?

По первому варианту `scoped_ptr p = new Object();` я вижу это так:

1. сначала выделяется память с помощью `new` по размеру объекта;
2. Cоздается объект типа `Object` c помощью конструктора `Object()`;
3. Далее объект `p` выстраивается по объекту типа `Object`, а если точнее, то в конструкторе копирования просто получает адрес принятого объекта и присваивает его указателю на объект `*pObj`. Ну вот и  объект "`p`" будет не указателем на объект, а просто объектом. А если бы было так `scoped_ptr *p = new Object();`, то была бы ошибка, потому что `*p` был бы указатем на один тип, а ему пытались присвоить адрес с другим типом.

По второму варианту `Object *p = new Object();` я вижу это так:

1. выделение памяти;
2. создание объекта по конструктору `Object()`.
3. Конструктор копирования не запускается, так как "`*p`" - это указатель на объект и ему сразу присваивается адрес.

Правильно ли я понял или где-то ошибся?

И ещё слышал, что запись вида `scoped_ptr p = new Object();`, а не `scoped_ptr p(new Object());` можно делать потому, что тип аргумента конструктора копий приводится к типу класса, если есть только один аргумент и по этому можно присваивать объектам данные того типа, который был в аргументе до неявного преобразования и по этому работает запись через "`=`", но в какой момент срабатывает это неявное преобразование?

Ведь если бы в начале, то получилось бы что `pObj = pObject;` `pObj` - указывает на тип `Object`, а `pObject` - указывает на тип `scoped_ptr` и была бы ошибка. Значит преобразование вообще не происходит? Тогда и это игнорируется `scoped_ptr p = scoped_ptr(new Object());`?

Если это явное приведение типов происходит, то как именно, создается временная копия объекта с этим типом и зачем она нужна, если параметр конструктора копий требует другой тип?

Comment: @mzarb: о, вы наткнулись на ещё одну фичу языка C++ -- copy constructor elision. По стандарту, компилятор имеет право выкидывать конструктор копирования и выполнять конструирование непосредственно целевого объекта, даже если этот конструктор что-то делает кроме собственно копирования (это единственное место в стандарте, где оптимизатору разрешается менять смысл программы). В gcc эту оптимизацию можно отключить: http://pastebin.com/Ah6XZDtQ (с ключом **`-fno-elide-constructors`** нужный конструктор работает).

---
Вот ещё по теме на SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12953127/276994

Comment: @mzarb: если сделать `scoped_ptr(const scoped_ptr& ptr)` приватным, не скомпилируется, так как для копирующей инициализации такой конструктор _должен_ быть (несмотря на то, что его потом выкинет оптимизатор). Таков стандарт.

Comment: @VladD, А почему деструктор для Object не запускается?

Comment: @mzarb: Потому что вы не удаляете объект, C++ за вас объект не удалит (так как в общем случае не знает, где он и когда его можно удалять). То есть у вас утечка памяти (aka memory leak).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ну вроде бы вы всё поняли почти правильно. На самом деле, указатель или не указатель, не имеет значения, правила для всех одинаковы.

Смотрите. Когда вы пишете

```
X x = y;
```

происходит совсем не то, что если бы вы написали

```
X x;
x = y;
```

В первом случае происходит *инициализация* объекта `x`, во втором случае -- *присваивание*. Для инициализации используется конструктор копирования. Это значит, что записи

```
X x = y;
```

и

```
X x(y);
```

равнозначны, и понимаются компилятором одинаково: в обоих случаях будет вызван конструктор копирования из типа `Y` (который является типом выражения `y`).

Рассмотрим ваш пример. Код

```
scoped_ptr p = new Object();
```

вызывает выполнение конструктора копирования типа `scoped_ptr` с аргументом типа `Object*` (ведь тип выражения `new Object()` как раз `Object*`). А код

```
Object *p = new Object();
```

точно так же вызывает конструктор копирования типа `Object*` (объект `p` у нас имеет тип `Object*`, вас не должно смущать, что звёздочка написана около `p`, на самом деле это всё равно что `Object* p`). Для типа указатель (которым является `Object*`) неявно определён конструктор копирования из указателя приводимого типа -- он просто копирует *значение* адреса.

Код `scoped_ptr *p = new Object();` бы не скомпилировался потому, что у типа `scoped_ptr*` нету конструктора копирования из типа `Object*`, ведь типы `scoped_ptr` и `Object` не родственны (а конструктор копирования для указателей есть только для родственных типов).

Записи `scoped_ptr p = new Object();` и `scoped_ptr p(new Object());` абсолютно равносильны, никакого неявного преобразования тут не происходит.

---

Заметьте, что с присваиванием немного сложнее. Если компилятор видит код

```
p = new Object();
```

где `p` имеет тип `scoped_ptr`, он пытается применить существующий оператор присваивания. Но у нас не определён явно оператор присваивания, и в этом случае C++ создаёт для нас оператор присваивания по умолчанию, который выглядит примерно так:

```
scoped_ptr& scoped_ptr::operator=(const scoped_ptr& other)
{
    pObj = other.pObj;
    return *this;
}
```

Итак, C++ пытается применить этот оператор присваивания, но тип нашего аргумента -- `Object*`, а не `scoped_ptr`. В этом случае компилятор проверяет, а нельзя ли сделать *неявное преобразование* типа `Object*` в `scoped_ptr`? Для такого преобразования подходит конструктор `scoped_ptr` с типом аргумента `Object*` (если он не объявлен со специальным ключевым словом `explicit`, которое предотвращает неявное преобразование). Итак, у нас сначала вызовется конструктор `scoped_ptr(Object*)`, и результат уйдёт оператору присваивания по умолчанию.

Вот вам маленький пример (добавлен оператор присваивания, выводящий текст):
http://ideone.com/968YYk.

---

Необходимое уточнение (уголок зануды).

На самом деле, конструкции `scoped_ptr p = new Object();` и `scoped_ptr p(new Object());` всё же немного отличаются.

Код `scoped_ptr p(new Object());` является вызовом конструктора `scoped_ptr` с аргументом типа `Object*`. Среди всех имеющихся конструкторов (их может быть несколько) выбираются подходящие (те, у которых первый аргумент может быть неявно сконвертирован в тип `Object*`, а остальные аргументы имеют значения по умолчанию), из них выбирается наиболее подходящий (точно так же, как и при нормальном вызове функции). Этот конструктор и вызывается; аргументы при необходимости подвергаются неявной конверсии.

В нашем случае у нас *два* конструктора: с аргументом типа `Object*` и с аргументом типа `const scoped_ptr&`, второй конструктор автоматически добавлен компилятором. Из этих конструкторов *оба* подходят (в первом аргумент точно соответствует, во втором аргумент может быть неявно сконвертирован при помощи, конечно, первого конструктора). Но первый подходит лучше, поэтому он и выбирается.

Такая инициализация называется [*прямой инициализацией*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).

Код `scoped_ptr p = new Object();` рассматривается компилятором немного по-другому. Во-первых, при рассмотрении вариантов не учитываются конструкторы с ключевым словом `explicit`. Это значит, что если бы конструктор `scoped_ptr(Object *pObject)` был помечен этим ключевым словом, наш код не скомпилировался бы. Далее, компилятор выбирает не любой конструктор, а неявно (или явно) определённый конструктор `scoped_ptr& operator=(const scoped_ptr& ptr)`. (Если этот конструктор [удалить](http://ideone.com/J0okRh) или сделать [приватным](http://ideone.com/boZIG1), код не откомпилируется.)

Итак, наш аргумент конструктора `Object*` должен неявно сконвертироваться в `scoped_ptr`. (Как уже сказано, для этого не подходят конструкторы, помеченные как `explicit`.) Таким образом, если при прямой инициализации рассматриваются конверсии через *любые* типы промежуточных аргументов, то здесь подходит лишь конверсия через `scoped_ptr`. Вот пример, когда эти пути могут быть различны: http://ideone.com/WhBk4R.

Финальный вызов копирующего конструктора может быть убран при оптимизации (обычно так и происходит).

Такая инициализация называется [*копирующей инициализацией*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

(Спасибо @Котик'у, указавшему на тонкость с `explicit`.)

Некоторые идеи подсмотрены [на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1051379/276994), советую почитать, кто хочет больше подробностей и ссылок на стандарт.

Comment: Спасибо, кажется разобрался. Добавлю в закладки чтобы не забывать. И за красивое форматирование текста спасибо:)

Comment: @mzarb: Пожалуйста! Вопрос на самом деле далеко не тривиальный.

Comment: @VladD, а почему здесь ошибка [http://ideone.com/WhBk4R][1], но в MSVC 2010 компилируется, правда с предупреждением "warning C4930: scoped_ptr p1(OtherObject (__cdecl *)(void)): функция с прототипом не вызвана (предполагалось определение переменной?)"? И ещё почему после этого `scoped_ptr p1(OtherObject());` вариант ничего не вызывает, а остальные три нормально работают?


  [1]: http://ideone.com/WhBk4R

Comment: mzarb: это известная багофича C++: компилятор понял конструкцию `scoped_ptr p1(OtherObject());` как forward-декларацию _функции_ с именем `p1`, возвращающую тип `scoped_ptr`, и принимающую аргумент типа `OtherObject()`, то есть функцию вида

    OtherObject f() { ... }

Соответственно этот код ничего и не делает. Делайте, например, так: http://ideone.com/VYBkoR

Comment: @mzarb: для второго варианта (`scoped_ptr p2 = OtherObject();`) у нас, как написано в ответе, происходит копирующая инициализация. Теперь компилятор не может пойти по пути "`OtherObject()` имеет тип `OtherObject`, оператор `operator Object*` может сконвертировать его в `Object*`, вызываем конструктор `scoped_ptr(Object *)`", т. к. финальный конструктор должен быть `scoped_ptr(const scoped_ptr&)`. То есть для такого варианта `OtherObject` недостаточно уметь сконвертировать в `Object *`, надо в `scoped_ptr`. Так что эта строчка правильно не компилируется.

Comment: @VladD, А почему он понял её как forward декларацию функции, ведь запись была не `OtherObject(*)()`? И почему все работает нормально(создается объект), если добавить скобки `scoped_ptr p1((OtherObject()));`?
А насчет `scoped_ptr p2 = OtherObject();`, не очень понял на каком моменте и из-за чего не получается, могли бы вы написать вариант в котором такая строчка скомпилируется? А в MSVC видимо из-за расширений каких-то компилируется, но с /za есть ошибка. Кстати /za лучше оставить, это же следование стандарту?

Comment: @mzarb: ну, `OtherObject(*)()` -- это _указатель_ на функцию, по идее (они совместимы). Когда вы добавили скобки, внутри, судя по всему, получается _выражение_, а не _тип_ -- но это продвинутые тонкости синтаксиса C++, всё равно такой трюк не стоит часто использовать. По поводу `p2` гляньте часть ответа с копирующей инициализацией. Скомпилируется, судя по всему, лишь так:

    scoped_ptr p2 = scoped_ptr(OtherObject());

Хотя, может, есть ещё трюки. (Однако трюки есть трюки, их стоит избегать и писать определения так, чтобы они были не нужны.)

Comment: @VladD, а в этом варианте `scoped_ptr p2 = scoped_ptr(OtherObject());` не понял что происходит в конце, если сделать scoped_ptr(const scoped_ptr& ptr) приватным членом, то будет ошибка, но а если не делать, то кажется работает, но почему то не выводит сообщение "in constructor scoped_ptr(const scoped_ptr&)". В чем может быть проблема?